# SAPUI5 PlanningCalender How to get the EndDate of the period

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I have a `PlanningCalender` element in my view.
There is a event property [startDateChange](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.PlanningCalendar/events/startDateChange) which is fired everytime the start date of the calender changes (click left or right to show other period).

You can get the actual start date using the `getStartDate()` method of the calender element class. Nevertheless, I also need to get the current end date of the calender. With the [intervalSelect](https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.PlanningCalendar/events/intervalSelect) event you can e.g. get the end date of the calender with the `getParameters` method. The `startDateChange` event does not offer me this option, so I need some alternative.

Is there some UI5 pro with a hint for me?

Comment: You could calculate the end date depending on the view key?

Comment: Doesn't the displayed period differ on the size of the window (e.g. if I minimize my browser window, it will show less days or months)? But can you maybe tell me how I get the current view key? Thanks!

Comment: You could try making a switch with all the keys and adding different additions depending on the key.

Comment: var startDate = this.byId("PC1").getStartDate();
var endDate = new Date(startDate);
endDate.setMonth(endDate.getMonth() + 1);

Answer (score 0):

you can calculate this value like this

```html
var startDate = oPlanningCalender.getStartDate();
var numberOfDays = oPlanningCalender._oDateInterval.getAggregation("month")[0].getProperty("days") - 1;
var endDate = new Date(
    startDate.getFullYear(),
   startDate.getMonth(),
   startDate.getDate() + numberOfDays,
   startDate.getHours(),
   startDate.getMinutes(),
   startDate.getSeconds()
  );
```